# the returned value from glsl function contain if statement

Tags: webgl, shader

I am a beginner with webgl programming, and still have more to learn.
I have found an existing fragment shader that contains this function:

```
float shadow(vec3 origin, vec3 ray) { 
    float tSphere0 = intersectSphere(origin, ray, sphereCenter0, sphereRadius0); 
    if(tSphere0 < 1.0) return 0.0; 
    float tSphere1 = intersectSphere(origin, ray, sphereCenter1, sphereRadius1); 
    if(tSphere1 < 1.0) return 0.0; 
    float tSphere2 = intersectSphere(origin, ray, sphereCenter2, sphereRadius2); 
    if(tSphere2 < 1.0) return 0.0; 
    float tSphere3 = intersectSphere(origin, ray, sphereCenter3, sphereRadius3); 
    if(tSphere3 < 1.0) return 0.0;  
    return 1.0;
}
```

My questions are: Will that function always return 1.0?
What does that function mean?

This is the function of intersectSphere

```
float intersectSphere(vec3 origin, vec3 ray, vec3 sphereCenter, float sphereRadius) {   
    vec3 toSphere = origin - sphereCenter;   
    float a = dot(ray, ray);   
    float b = 2.0 * dot(toSphere, ray);   
    float c = dot(toSphere, toSphere) - sphereRadius*sphereRadius;   
    float discriminant = b*b - 4.0*a*c;   
    if(discriminant > 0.0) {     
        float t = (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / (2.0 * a);     
        if(t > 0.0) return t;   }   
    return 10000.0; 
}
```

Comment: you didn't provide the function. The function `intersectSphere` is not part of WebGL. It's a user supplied function. Just guessing though it looks like it will return 1.0 if the vector origin -> ray intersects all 4 spheres, otherwise it returns 0.0. As for what it means. It means "return 1 if the vector origin->ray intersects all 4 spheres. Otherwise return 0"

Comment: Can you post the source code for `intersectSphere`?